# Is commit history lost if file is not changed?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Wanted to clarify if I'm running into issue mentioned here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/missing-commits-in-bitbucket-server-785327849.html

or if it's expected git behavior so I can really understand the situation.

So I merged a feature branch and force merged it into my bitbucket repo.

However I'm noticing that some of the commit history is lost when I check it in bitbucket for a certain file.

Let's say it's "File A". In the "feature branch" I made several commits with some changes but ultimately the last commit was a commit that reverted it back to what the file was in "master". So "File A" ended up being the same in both the "feature branch" and "master" when I merged.

Is it expected that all the commit history for "File A" is lost in the "master" branch if there are no changes to the file? Is there anyway to keep the commit history regardless of if the file didn't change but there were commits to it?

That would mean that closing the branch would result in those commits being lost right?

I tested by just adding a comma in the "feature branch" "File A" and when I merged the commit history does show.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: The *commits* are never lost, as long as they are in the commit graph. The tricky part is that when you ask Git: *how did file A become the way it is today* and there's a merge that ends up not-changing file A, Git assumes that there's no need to *show* the set of commits that ended up not-changing the file. From the command line, you must add `--full-history` to your `git log` command. If you are using some sort of graphical viewer, find out how *it* instructs Git to follow all history even if it *looks* irrelevant at first glance.

Comment: Besides the above, there's no such thing as a "force merge". There are real merges, which `git merge --no-ff` always makes, and fast-forward operations that aren't merges, which `git merge --ff-only` does. Running `git merge` from the command line, without specifying either `--no-ff` or `--ff-only`, does a fast-forward instead of a merge, if and only if the fast-forward is possible, otherwise it does a real merge. The "force" they're referring to above is `git push --force`.

Comment: It's a `git push --force` (or the equivalent from some graphical viewer) that can discard commits from the commit-graph. Both a real merge, and a fast-forward not-actually-a-merge, retain the commits in the graph. The "history becomes invisible without `--full-history`" case occurs only with real merges, and based on the description above, that sounds like the one you're seeing.